# java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed in Camera Api

Tags: android, camera

I am developing Camera overly app in that i am using camera api for preview and overlay effects.I am getting force close error in some mobiles and it is not happening other mobiles.

My code:

```
parameters = camera.getParameters(); 
List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h); 
parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE);
setCameraDisplayOrientation(MainActivity.this,0, camera); 
camera.getParameters(); 
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

These are the call stacks I am getting

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1046)
    at com.androidpixels.watercamera.MainActivity.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:1241)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:575)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:407)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:352)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1917)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1530)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1266)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me. what could be the reason?

Comment: We can't guess anything without seeing some code.

Comment: Posting only logcat doesn't make sense for anyone to find the issue in your code without checking code. so i think you need to submit some code also.

Comment: i am using this link http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-android-application-development-isbn-978-0-470-34471-2/72528-article-using-android-camera.html

Comment: getOptimalPreviewSize,   where is this method in Camera class ?

Answer (score 7):

**Android Camera Parameters** vary between devices. you need to verify that the device supports the parameter you're trying to set before setting it, see this [Camera SetParameters Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setParameters%28android.hardware.Camera.Parameters%29)

You can query the *Supported Parameters* by :

- Obtain a Parameters object : `Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();`
- Then query that object for specific Parameter , say PreviewSize:

  params.getSupportedPreviewSizes ()

Comment: yes i using parameters = camera.getParameters();
 
 List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
 
 Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);
 
 parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
 
 parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE);

 setCameraDisplayOrientation(MainActivity.this,0, camera);
 camera.getParameters();
 camera.setParameters(parameters);